# Retrieving data from af::array via host() results in wrong data

Tags: c++, arrayfire

When trying to retrieve data from an `af::array` ([arrayfire](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire)) from the device via `host()`, my output data on the host is wrong (i.e. wrong values). For testing that, I wrote a small code sample (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29212923/2546099):

```
int main(void) {  
    size_t vector_size = 16;
    af::array in_test_array = af::constant(1., vector_size), out_test_array = af::constant(0., vector_size);

    af_print(in_test_array);
    double *local_data_ptr = new double[vector_size]();

    for(int i = 0; i < vector_size; ++i)
        std::cout << local_data_ptr[i] << '\t';
    std::cout << '\n';
    in_test_array.host(local_data_ptr);
    for(int i = 0; i < vector_size; ++i)
        std::cout << local_data_ptr[i] << '\t';
    std::cout << '\n';
    delete[] local_data_ptr;
    out_test_array = in_test_array;
    af_print(out_test_array);
    return 0;
}
```

My output is

```
in_test_array
[16 1 1 1]
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 

0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0.007813        0.007813        0.007813        0.007813        0.007813        0.007813        0.007813        0.007813        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
out_test_array
[16 1 1 1]
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000 
    1.0000
```

Why are half the values in the pointer set to `0.007813`, and not all values to `1`? When changing the default value for `in_test_array` to `2`, half the values are set to `2`, and for `3` those values are set to `32`. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatypes between arrayfire and C are in conflict.

For float use:

```
af::array in_test_array = af::constant(1., vector_size), 
          out_test_array = af::constant(0., vector_size);
float *local_data_ptr = new float[vector_size]();
```

For double use:

```
af::array in_test_array = af::constant(1., vector_size, f64),
          out_test_array = af::constant(0., vector_size, f64)
double *local_data_ptr = new double[vector_size]();
```

IN both cases above, you will see that arrayfire will return you 1.0 in the local_data_ptr buffer, although with different data types.